# Quadratic models with R. The use of poly(..) and I(..) functions (R-language)

Tags: r, regression, quadratic-form

What causes the different results below?

```
var1 = c(0.04875,0.13725,0.28350,0.50975,0.77425,0.94700,0.05325,0.14050,0.29725,0.51525,0.79000,0.95400,0.04625,0.15250,0.29000,0.53300,0.79825,0.95225,0.05025,0.14625,0.28800,0.52625,0.78200,0.95925,0.04700,0.14225,0.30325,0.53500,0.79325,0.95875,0.04775,0.13850,0.28675,0.54250,0.78300,0.95175,0.05150,0.12725,0.30175,0.54725,0.79475,0.96275,0.05375,0.14100,0.30050,0.53275,0.78100,0.96175,0.05450,0.15300,0.29650,0.52850,0.80100,0.95675,0.05425,0.13975,0.30875,0.56025,0.80575,0.96100,0.05100,0.15350,0.31175,0.53300,0.78900,0.96000,0.04650,0.13525,0.29600,0.53625,0.78475,0.96375,0.05375,0.13900,0.29600,0.53725,0.78700,0.95800,0.05075,0.14350,0.29225,0.54525,0.80275,0.95800,0.05050,0.13200,0.29850,0.52700,0.80525,0.96150,0.05150,0.14050,0.29450,0.54375,0.79450,0.96375,0.05375,0.13525,0.30475,0.55250,0.79425,0.96025,0.04950,0.14500,0.29425,0.52250,0.78475,0.95650,0.05225,0.14425,0.29225,0.53150,0.80425,0.95375)

var2 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6)

var3 = c(4,4,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6,6,8,8,8,8,8,8,10,10,10,10,10,10,12,12,12,12,12,12,14,14,14,14,14,14,16,16,16,16,16,16,18,18,18,18,18,18,20,20,20,20,20,20,22,22,22,22,22,22,24,24,24,24,24,24,26,26,26,26,26,26,28,28,28,28,28,28,30,30,30,30,30,30,32,32,32,32,32,32,34,34,34,34,34,34,36,36,36,36,36,36,38,38,38,38,38,38,40,40,40,40,40,40)


summary(aov(var1~as.factor(var2)*var3))
summary(aov(var1~as.factor(poly(var2,1))*poly(var3,1)))
```

I might not understand well how poly(..) and I(..) work. Could you give me some hints about these two functions?

(I aim to create models of different degree (quadratic, cubic, etc..) and compare their BIC (or AIC)).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have the first model all sorts of wrong; that model

```
var1 ~ var2 * var3
```

says the variance in `var1` is explained by the main effects of factor `var2` and continuous covariate `var3` *and* their interaction. In other words, the model is one where each level of `var2` has a separate *intercept* and *slope* for the regressions lines fitted. There are no polynomials here.

The second model is wrong also, but what you *actually* want is unclear from the description given. That model

```
var1 ~ poly(var2,1) * poly(var3,1)
```

where you cast `poly(var2,1)` as a factor is effectively the same as the first, just with extra effort.

`poly()` generates orthogonal (by default) polynomials of its first argument of degree specified by the second argument. Hence the first order polynomial of `1:10` is

```
> poly(1:10, 1)
                1
 [1,] -0.49543369
 [2,] -0.38533732
 [3,] -0.27524094
 [4,] -0.16514456
 [5,] -0.05504819
 [6,]  0.05504819
 [7,]  0.16514456
 [8,]  0.27524094
 [9,]  0.38533732
[10,]  0.49543369
attr(,"degree")
[1] 1
attr(,"coefs")
attr(,"coefs")$alpha
[1] 5.5

attr(,"coefs")$norm2
[1]  1.0 10.0 82.5

attr(,"class")
[1] "poly"   "matrix"
```

The second orthogonal polynomial of the vector `1:10` is essentially `1:10` and `(1:10) * (1:10)` but done in a way as to make the two new vectors orthogonal (or uncorrelated)

```
> poly(1:10, 2)
                1           2
 [1,] -0.49543369  0.52223297
 [2,] -0.38533732  0.17407766
 [3,] -0.27524094 -0.08703883
 [4,] -0.16514456 -0.26111648
 [5,] -0.05504819 -0.34815531
 [6,]  0.05504819 -0.34815531
 [7,]  0.16514456 -0.26111648
 [8,]  0.27524094 -0.08703883
 [9,]  0.38533732  0.17407766
[10,]  0.49543369  0.52223297
attr(,"degree")
[1] 1 2
attr(,"coefs")
attr(,"coefs")$alpha
[1] 5.5 5.5

attr(,"coefs")$norm2
[1]   1.0  10.0  82.5 528.0

attr(,"class")
[1] "poly"   "matrix"
```

I'm not clear what you want, but if you want to explore models for different polynomials of `var2` and `var3` then just use

```
var1 ~ poly(var2, 2) + poly(var3, 2)
```

for main effects of quadratic polynomials of `var2` and `var3`. Or more complex

```
var1 ~ poly(var2, 2) * poly(var3, 3)
```

which is the main effects of a quadratic in `var2` and a cubic in `var3`, *plus* their interaction.

`I( )` *isolates* or *insulates* the contents in the parentheses from R's formula parsing code. For example, you might commonly see

```
var1 ~ var2 + var2^2 + var3 + var3^2
```

which is the same as `var1 ~ poly(var2, 2) + poly(var3, 2)` (except the polynomials are not orthogonal), or it *should be*. Unfortunately, `^` in a formula means ordered terms, i.e. itself plus its interaction, because `^` has special meaning. To stop R interpreting `^` incorrectly, you wrap those terms in `I( )`. i.e.

```
var1 ~ var2 + I(var2^2) + var3 + I(var3^2)
```

However, do note that `var2` and `I(var2^2)` will be correlated (likewise for `var3` and `I(var3^2)`) and correlated variables in a model can cause issues. Hence the use of `poly()` which produces orthogonal polynomials, as discussed above.

Note also that `poly()` can give you the usual raw polynomials via use of `raw = TRUE`. Hence this might be more what you were expecting for the quadratic of the vector `1:10`

```
> poly(1:10, 2, raw = TRUE)
       1   2
 [1,]  1   1
 [2,]  2   4
 [3,]  3   9
 [4,]  4  16
 [5,]  5  25
 [6,]  6  36
 [7,]  7  49
 [8,]  8  64
 [9,]  9  81
[10,] 10 100
attr(,"degree")
[1] 1 2
attr(,"class")
[1] "poly"   "matrix"
```

But `poly(1:10, 2)` would be better in a model.

Comment: This is agreat answer to a not-so-easy-to-answer question! thanks GavinSimpson! I got all the stuff about I() and poly(). But I'm not sure about the effect that as.factor has. And did you actually make a mistake on the very first grey box of your answer? didn't you mean to use as.factor on var2? When would someone use a factor in the formula? When the thing it applies on is considered as a covariate?

Comment: @Remi.b Thanks. I removed `as.factor` intentionally and stated that I assumed that `var2` was a factor already - to simplify things. `as.factor(var2)` would create a factor and thus it would be expanded to $l - 1$ columns in the model matrix (assuming the default contrasts and inclusion of an intercept). I wouldn't use `as.factor()` in a formula - you should separate the model fitting from the data analysis code, but people do and it is valid as `model.frame` arranges for the function to be called as it is creating the data from which to build the model matrix.

Comment: OK! But still, I don't really get what it means that "`as.factor(var2)` would create a factor and thus it would be expanded to **l-1** columns in the model matrix" Why would someone use such a model? Maybe giving a practical example of experimental design where someone would use a factor migh help me! Many Thks

Comment: R might have read in the values `c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,2,2,1,2)` as an *integer* vector. If these are classes, the *wrong* model, using 1 df for this variable, would be fitted. The $l-1$ columns represent, using default contrasts, the difference in means between the reference level (which the intercept represents) and each other level/class in the factor. Consider a variable `Treatment` taking values `c(0, 5, 10, 50)` where `0` is the control. R will most likely *not* read that in as a factor and if you plug that into `aov()` it would use a single df and treat `Treatment` as a linear covariate.

Comment: OK! Thks a lot GavinSimpson for your help!

Comment: Also it should be noted that the orthogonal polynomials generated by R add extra wrinkles in terms of interpreting your regression coefficients.  If you want to know the size of the effect in real terms you'd have to back out the transformation that poly (raw=FALSE, the default) does.  I'm give to understand that you can get most of the way to the advantage of poly by mean centering your variables prior to calculating your interaction terms.

Comment: @rpierce +1 Good point. We have this issue fitting a particular model to species abundance data. Coefficients fitted with `poly(x,2)` difficult to be interpreted in terms of the underlying theoretical model...