# interpreting R lm(..) output when a variable is used as a factor

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, factor-analysis, model

Below is a print screen of a summary(lm(..)).

I called the response variable `response` explained by a continuous variable `X` and a factor `Y`.

[image]

I'm trying to understand (not to the point of understanding the algorithms used to compute these results) the meaning of this output. My questions might be duplicates, but I haven't found the answer anywhere or if I did, I couldn't understand it!

- The model is `response = -4.461010 + blabla..`. What does the p.value for this intercept mean? Does it mean that the predicted line of my data significantly does not pass by the Origin?
- `factor(Y)2` is significant. Does it mean that for the subset of `data2` where `Y` equals 2, the values of `response` are significantly different than in the subset where `Y`equals 1 (which is taken as a reference)?
- Imagine a graph where the lines for `subset(data2,Y==1)` and `subset(data2,Y==2)` look alike but the line for `subset(data2,Y==3)` is totally different. If `factor(Y)3` is taken as a reference, we'll get the two others to be significant and if `factor(Y)1` is taken as a reference, `factor(Y)3` will be significant but not `factor(Y)2`. Is it correct?
- For the interactions `X:Y2` and `X:Y3`. Does the low p.values mean that for both the subset  `Y==2` and `Y==3`, the variable `X` acts differently than it does for the subset `Y==1`?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You might want to clarify what your data are and what your question is. I suspect that you want to know if there are main effects of $X$ and $Y$ and an interaction between the two, in which case you might want to run `anova(lm(..))`.

Comment: No, I don't want to use the `anova` function. I think I understand the results of the anova. I just don't understand the output of the `summary(lm(..))`. Do my above questions make sense? It is really the meaning of each line in the output example that interests me.

Comment: Because you ask multiple questions I can only identify one official "duplicate."  The meaning of `poly` is explained at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66280. The interpretation of interactions is explained in many threads: do a [search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interaction?sort=votes). Interpreting regression coefficients is explained in many threads; this one also explains the p-values and `R`'s output: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5135.

Comment: @whuber I know what poly means. And I found the last link you gave me. I don't think, it provides the answer to my questions concerning the meaning of the p.values when using factors. Or if it does, I don't get it.

Comment: In that case [reading about p-values](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value?sort=vote) may help. If it doesn't, then consider editing this question to focus on whatever you are specifically struggling with that is not addressed in any of those other answers.